# Value of a function is than its integral.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f(x)$ is nonnegative and Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, is it true that

$ f(c)\leq \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$

for any $c\in[a,b]$?

- The same question assuming Lebesgue integrability.
  Thanks

Comment: No. Let $f(x)=1$ and $[a,b]=[0,0.5]$. Then the integral is $1/2$ but $f(c)=1>1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

No, take $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$:
$$
\int_0^1 x\,dx=\frac{1}{2}
$$
while $f(1)=1$.

This of course is a counterexample also for the second question.

Both for Lebesgue and Riemann integrals, in any case, you can't deduce nothing about the value at a point, because the integral doesn't change if you modify the value on a finite set of points.

Answer (score 0):

As another example, take $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for $x \in [\epsilon, 1]$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$ for $x\in[0,\epsilon]$ (with fixed $\epsilon$ of course).

Then $f$ is nonnegative, continuous and its integral is less than $\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}}=2$. But $f$ can take values as large as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}$, which is larger than $2$ for small enough $\epsilon$.